# Python Numpy Complexe number "Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'"

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my problem, I'm trying to create numerical holograms using python (3.7) and I happen to have this error

> Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('int64')
>   according to the rule 'safe'

What can I do to correct it ?

Here is my code :

````py
import numpy as np
import pylab as py
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib as plt


Jmax=256
q=np.zeros([Jmax,Jmax])
for l in range (Jmax):
    for j in range(Jmax):
        q[j,l]=1
for j in range (100,150):
  for i in range (100,150):
    q[i,j]=0



py.pcolormesh(q,cmap=plt.cm.gray, antialiased=True)
py.colorbar()
py.show()

l=.1*10**(-9) #wavelengh lambda
z1=40*10**(-9) #z1
#Wave equation tz1(x)
tz1=np.zeros([Jmax,Jmax],dtype=complex)

x=np.arange(-int(Jmax/2),int(Jmax/2),1)
y=np.arange(-int(Jmax/2),int(Jmax/2),1)
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)

tz1=np.exp( -1j*np.pi*(xx**2+yy**2) / z1*l ) 

py.pcolormesh(tz1,cmap=plt.cm.gray, antialiased=True)
py.show()

#fft = Fast Fourier Transform
k=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(q))
T=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(tz1) )
#convolution
phi=np.array([])
phi=np.fft.ifft2(k*T) 
#Explanation of the fftshift : https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/routines.fft.html?highlight=fft#module-numpy.fft
phi=np.fft.fftshift(phi)
phiconj=np.conj(phi)
#Intensity calculus
I=phi*phiconj
I=np.real(I)
#Here,cmap=plt.cm.gray, antialiased=True allow the pcolormesh to be in black and white.
py.pcolormesh(I,cmap=plt.cm.gray, antialiased=True)
py.colorbar()
py.show()


I1=Image.fromarray(I)
#Here I have to use PIl.Image.Image 
I2=Image.Image.resize(self=I1,size=[256,256])
Image.Image.save(fp="Hologramme test 5.tif",self=I2) ```

Thank you in advance for your anwsers.
PS : I'm an ESL, so if you do not understand one of my sentence, plese tell me. I'll try to write it again so that it is easier to understand.
````

Comment: Where does the error occur?  Looks like you have a complex array (`tz1`?) that you are trying to assign to, or insert, in an integer array.  Or use where an integer array is expected.

Comment: I think the error happens when the FFT of tz1 : T and the one of q : k are multiplied. Because q is an integer at the start of the program. But I don't understand, because it was working well at first.

Comment: The error message should tell you exactly where the error occurs.  No need to guess.

Comment: It does not, I'm on Spyder and it shows me the error in the code behind the scene, but not the position of the exact error. 
If it was IDLE it would have been easier I guess to find the error position but I don't know how to install packages, so I did my best using Spyder.

Comment: I'm used to seeing a `traceback` which would lead all the way back to your code.  In any case, you are providing a complex argument where the code expects an integer one.  It could be the `fft` calls, one of the plot ones, or `Image`.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs @hpaulj. I'll try some more. Have a good day !